# One-way function definition

Tags: one-way-function

I cannot understand why a one-way function $f$ is defined in this way

$\text{Pr}(f(A(f(x))) = f(x)) < \frac{1}{p(n)}$

and not

$\text{Pr}(A(f(x)) = x) < \frac{1}{p(n)}$

where $A$ is a randomized algorithm.

Where is the difference? Is the second one weaker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two conditions indeed represent different things. Consider the function that, given an $n$-bit input, returns $n$ zeroes. This clearly meets the second definition (if you have $n$ zeroes, a randomized algorithm has just a $1/2^n$ chance of guessing the input, because *any* $n$-bit input returns that output), but it also clearly fails the first ($A$ is just "return $0^n$"). So the first condition is not weaker than the second; in fact, anything failing the second clearly fails the first (you just use the same algorithm $A$, and use $A(f(x))=x$ and so $f(A(f(x)))=f(x)$). So the first is in fact stronger than the second.

The key difference between the two is that the second is just about finding the *exact* input we fed into the function. If a function meets this condition, then it means an attacker who knows the output isn't going to figure out our actual input. But that's often not what we're concerned about. In many schemes, it's a problem if the attacker can find *any* input to get a given output, whether or not it's the actual input we used. Condition 2 asks for *the* inverse; condition 1 just ask for *an* inverse, and if the function isn't one-to-one there's a difference between the two. In crypto, one-way functions tend to be used where finding *an* inverse is a problem.

To use a password hash as an example, suppose my password is `swordfish`, which hashes to `ABCDE1234`, and the hash function meets condition 2 but not condition 1. Because of (2) you can't efficiently figure out that my password is `swordfish`, but because it fails (1) you can find *something* that hashes to `ABCDE1234` (say, `letmein12`). Sure, you didn't get my password, but you found *some* inverse of `ABCDE1234`, and it doesn't help me that you didn't get my password - `letmein12` works just as well for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that one of them is useful, and the other is trivial to achieve. $\:$ The second one
is weaker because all constant functions with super-polynomially growing domains satisfy it.